# Tilemaker: include_ids and OSM ID

Tags: openstreetmap, maplibre-gl

I'm currently using tilemaker https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md to generate mbtiles from osm pbf files.

I'm setting, in the config file, the parameter `include_ids` to `true` to generate in each mbtiles object (node or way) the original osm ID.

```
"settings": {
        "include_ids": true,
        ...
        }
```

What I don't understand so far is that the ID which is generated by Tilemaker is actually not the original OSM ID, that I can fetch via `obj:Id()`

Is there any reason why tilemaker ID generated via the 'include_ids = true` is actually not the expected osm id from the initial source ?

I'm using `queryRenderedFeatures` from `maplibre` to verify the content of my mbtiles, and for instance I have

```
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "osm_id": "4349756002",
      "name:latin": "Gilgamesch",
    },
    "id": 1103861383778,
    "layer": {
      "id": "poi",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "openmaptiles",
      "source-layer": "poi",
      "metadata": {},
      "minzoom": 15.5,
      "layout": {
        "text-font": [
```

where `"osm_id": "4349756002"` is the real node id from OSM (that I'm manually getting from `obj:Id()` from the pbf) and `"id": 1103861383778` is the one generated by `tilemaker`. I can confirm that the expected osm id is https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/details.html?osmtype=N&osmid=4349756002

Anyone able to shed a light on what I'm doing wrong? Curious if there is mask to apply to go from `1103861383778` to `4349756002``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowest 40 bits of feature.id is real OSM id, and the rest encodes type of object:
1=node, 2=way, 3=relation.
See [include/output_object.h](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/blob/57942b9812e1e3c7b5ec0f46820fa853f36f3c44/include/output_object.h#L20) in TileMaker source.
So:

```
osmId = feature.id & 0xffffffffff;
osmType = feature.id >>> 40;
```